# Problem with connecting ProxySQL from remote computer

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-aurora-serverless, amazon-linux-2, proxysql

> **I just solved my problem, thanks for your help!**

I'm a developer who wants to connect to the aurora serverless (mysql) through the ec2 instance using ProxySQL.

The ec2 instance is running on Amazon Linux 2.

I tried to connect from my computer using this command.

```
mysql -u<username> -p<password> -h <my instance's public address> -P6033
```

but kept getting this error.

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '<my address>' (110)
```

So I tried to check all the settings that can block connecting to the server, and here are the links I pasted the results.

1. netstat -nlt from the server : https://pastebin.com/m5tkX2kf
2. ProxySQL's variable settings : https://pastebin.com/MNJLHFQt
3. AWS Security Group settings : https://pastebin.com/EX4WtKtQ
4. AWS Network ACL settings : https://pastebin.com/Re3MEs4Q
5. Result of using namp from my computer : https://pastebin.com/zStYLEsA

But still can't find why I can't connect from my desktop.

Could you tell me why I can't connect and what I have to do?
I really appreciate it if you let me know how to fix it.

Many thanks!

Comment: Hey, are they both in the same VPC, likely to be default?

Comment: yeah, it is in the same VPC just as the default settings.

Comment: When you say "I can't connect from my desktop" do you mean the ec2 instance that is running on Amazon Linux 2?

Comment: Yes, ec2 is running on Amazon Linux 2, and I'm trying to get there with my desktop. But I managed to connect to the ec2 now so it's ok. thanks for your help anyways!